# Apex Chart - inapropriate sorting

Tags: bar-chart, oracle-apex

Below the chart which causes problems

[image]

There are hundreds of items .  Every day each item appears a several times. My idea was

1. to show only items which appears most frequent (at least MIN.PERCENTAGE value)
2. sum all other items which appears less than value of MIN.PERCENTAGE
   and add them as "Others".

When you look at bar from 2022-07-11 data are displayed correctly. All others (next) bars are also OK but Item which not exists 11th appears always on top of bar. And sorting does not work anymore :(  It seems that sorting is always as in the first bar.
Below the data I use

[image]

And mapping from chart settings:

SERIES NAME: ITEM

LABEL: DATE

VALUE: COUNT

Any finally the sql query :

```
select   date
        , item
        , count
        , rank
  from source 
 where OK is not null    //  ok means percentage >= P10_PERCENT
union all
select  date
        , 'others'
        , sum(count)
        , 999 
  from source 
 where ok is null  /// sum all items with percentage < P10_PERCENT
 group by date
 order by 1 , 4 desc
```

Why only the first bar is sorted correctly?
Why "new" items  appears always on top of the bar. How to force sorting every bar according to data from query ?

Any ideas ? Any help ?

Comment: You didn't post query that provides data for those charts. Did you use ORDER BY clause? If not, you won't get proper result.

Comment: Yes I use ORDER BY .   I have some new conclusions so I will do changes in my question in a minute

Comment: Done .  So now the main question is :   how to keep sort from query in every displayed bar :)